# Why do people still use classical logic?

Tags: logic, foundations-of-mathematics

It seems to me very crazy that mathematicians reactions to Godël incompleteness theorem have been mostly to agree that there are statements of the language which can neither be proved nor disproved but to continue to use such a language without any matter of conscience.

The only good interpretation of Godel Theorem is : classical logic is not suited as a foundation for mathematics. The use of classical logic in mathematics is the importation of a vernacular mistake into mathematics, whereas the only goal of a formal language is to avoid such a mistake.

Often people don't realize that Godel Theorem do not apply in a constructive logic. Actually, the theorem could be written but it only proves something about classical logic. The godel sentence is constructed as a classical logic sentence and actually as a string of characters, but to construct a sentence in a constructive logic is much more than to build a classical logic sentence, the inductive construction has to encompass an inductive meaning, which obviously forbid to construct a Godel sentence with no provable meaning (because the proof is directly given by the induction scheme).

I only found two arguments to not throw away classical logic, but they seem very weak to me :

- The classical logic is implementing the excluded middle principle. But it is obvious that you can build the sentence 'P or not P' in a constructive logic if you have previously given a valid (which encompass an inductive meaning) construction for P. Actually excluded middle leads to incompleteness results in classical logic only for sentences that could not have been constructed in a constructive logic. It is a necessary gateway for incompleteness, but the mistake of classical logic is not in a particular inference rule, it is in the way inference rules apply to sentences indepently of a meaning it would have.
- To reject the classical logic would lead to reject too much existing work and theories. But either these theories have not been properly formalized or they have no provable meaning. This is a very very strange conception of either science or truth. It seems to me that the more you can reject you should reject it, to keep only the genuinely essential. I have never seen a mathematician saying "my theory with 27 axioms could be reduced to a theory with 3 axioms, but I prefer to keep the 27 because I do not want to reject too many axioms". This is crazy, it seems to me that mathematics have been betrayed by mathematicians.

What would be arguments to not throw away classical logic ? Even if no one has autority to do so.

Addendum : What I mean by **constructive logic** is a logic where you can only build a sentence by induction and the induction has to encompass an inductive meaning. For example : before to write the syntax of "P AND Q" you need not only a syntax of P and a syntax of Q but also an interpretation of P and an interpretation of Q and these interpretations have to be consistent if there is a shared variable. In a *constructive logic* you can't even introduce a sentence which would not be proved. May be intuitionistic type theory is a constructive logic but I have to go into the details. I think we can define a **classical logic** as : any other logic.

Comment: Related question : https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10583/references-for-intuitionistic-meta-logic

Comment: "reactions to Godel incompleteness theorem have been mostly to agree that there are statements of the language which ..." are due to the fact that from classical point of view (where bi-valence is assumed) the expectations were that also axioms systems for arithmetic are complete wrt intended model, in a similar way that first-order proof systems are complete wrt validity. G's 1st IT showed that the expectation is not correct, and this were not an "impressive" result for Intuitionism that do not share the belief that every mathematical problem has a definite solution.

Comment: Is GIT a confutation of classical logic? Not at all, we can still use it in many context, like e.g. boolean logic for computers. In the same way we can use "classical" Newtonian mechanics to define the trajectory of a rocket landing on the Moon, despite the fact that from the point of view of Relativity the former is "false".

Comment: A very deep result of Godel (again) is that if Intuitionistic Logic is consistent, so is classical one.

Comment: I agree that GIT is interesting because it refutes the expectation we had about classical logic. But the fact that we can use classical logic is not an argument to use it. We can use vernacular language everywhere. It is consistent but it is not minimal and these meaningless statements flood the others.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking specifically, why do *mathematicians* use classical logic? I think the answer simply resides in the simplicity and power of classical logic. It has a nice simple boolean algebra. It is provably sound and complete with respect to standard model theory. It provides a particularly simple understanding of negation: if a proposition is not true, it is false; and if it is not false, it is true.

Non-classical logics are sometimes used in mathematics, but for most mathematicians they give unsatisfactory results. They may fail to allow important theorems to be proved. For example, one can create a 'relevant arithmetic' by closing Peano Arithmetic under relevance logic, but all kinds of important theorems of classical arithmetic are no longer provable. In other cases, non-classical logics give strange results that are difficult to interpret. There are published papers in paraconsistent set theory, for example, and even in inconsistent mathematics, but these tend to lead to an inconsistent representation of the truth predicate.

Intuitionistic logic is used within constructive mathematics, but most mathematicians regard it as too restrictive for general purposes. Sometimes it is OK to prove that something exists by *reductio*, without having to exhibit a witness. Of course, if you personally don't agree with that, you are welcome to confine your study of mathematics to the constructive fragment of it, but it doesn't make the problems of incompleteness and inconsistency go away. Also, constructivism does not circumvent Gödel's first incompleteness theorem, since Gödel's proof is entirely constructive and goes through using intuitionistic logic.

When you speak of 'meaning', it is fair to say that classical logic and intuitionistic logic differ in their underlying theory of meaning. This was a point argued by Michael Dummett, who was himself a firm advocate of intuitionistic logic. Classical logic can be understood as the logic of what holds true of some reality that is independent of us, whereas intuitionistic logic is often understood as the logic of what is demonstrable. In simple terms, classical logic is realist, while intuitionistic logic is antirealist. So perhaps another answer to your question is that a lot of mathematicians are closet realists: they believe that mathematical propositions just are true or false, even if we can't prove them, and incompleteness is something we can live with.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that by "classical logic", you mean first-order logic. First-order logic is complete, meaning that anything that is true in the model is derivable from the axioms.

No system powerful enough to do arithmetic is complete (where "arithmetic" means something at least as powerful as Peano arithmetic), therefore, classical logic is not adequate for arithmetic. The Peano axioms have a second-order axiom called the Axiom of Induction:

```
forall functions f(if f(0) and forall i(f(i) implies f(i+1)) then forall i(f(i)))
```

This is a second order axiom because it quantifies over a function.

There are various alternatives to this function (such as an Axiom of Well-Orderedness), but all such alternatives that produce a system as powerful as Peano arithmetic are second order.

So if your question is based on the idea that Gödel's incompleteness theorem applies to first order logic, that is a misunderstanding. In fact, it was Gödel who proved the completeness of first order logic. On the other hand, second order logic is not complete, as one can infer from the fact that second order logic is powerful enough to do Peano arithmetic.

As to the reason not to throw out second order logic, it is not just that it has the law of the excluded middle or that some work will be lost, the reason is that there are lots of true theorems that cannot be proven by constructive logic (or first order logic). Constructive or first order logic alone is not powerful enough to do arithmetic.

And what would be the motivation for throwing out second order logic? Just referring to incompleteness is not a justification; you have to explain why that is unacceptable. It's clear why it's unfortunate; it would be nice to have complete arithmetic, but what is the value of throwing out true theories just because they cannot be proven by a certain kind of system?

Comment: It is not about first order or second order. By classical logic I mean any logic where you can build a syntactic proposition which doesn't encompass an inductive meaning. 

You say no system powerful enough to do arithmetic is complete. I would say no **classical logic system** powerful enough to do **classical logic formalization of arithmetic** is a **classical logic 
 complete** system. 

I think a good example of a constructive logic could be intuitionistic type theory. I don't know this theory but it seems to be what I call a constructive logic.

Comment: @François, your definition of classical logic is peculiar to you. If you are going to use such idiosyncratic definitions, you need to spell them out in the question. If you had done so, I could have simply pointed out that intuitionistic type theory and all other constructive logics fit your definition of a classical logic. Also, your sentence beginning with "I would say no classical logic system..." has no meaning in normal logic terminology. You are going to have to spell it out in more standard terminology.

Comment: Yes it is a good point. In a constructive logic you can only build a sentence by induction and the induction has to encompass an inductive meaning. For example : before to write the syntax of "p AND q" you should have already built not only a syntax of p and a syntax of q but also an interpretation of p and an interpretation of q (and these interpretations have to be consistent if there is a shared variable). May be intuitionistic type theory is a constructive logic but I have to go into the details. I think we can define a classical logic as : any other logic.

Comment: @François, you are also going to have to spell out what you mean by "induction". I only know two definitions of induction--one for logic and one for mathematics, and neither seems to fit what you are saying.

Comment: It only means that I build the sentence as a tree using inference rules. I have to build p and q in order to build p^q. It means that you already know the interprétation of any variable you would use as leaf of the tree, because the goal of syntax is to encode some pre-existing semantics and not to decide something

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had a similar question. Since I am a software developer, I wondered if there is any kind of logic calculus to handle state. Classical logic is state-less, or as one could say time-less and therefore inadequate to express the state in a system with memory. As far as i knew, only differential equations are sufficient to express such self-referentialness as time dependant states. So, my question is, is computer science ahead of classical logic in the sense, that in computer science, the same statement can be true or false, depending on the time? To say it a little more philosophical: are there truths that are time dependent? And if so, why hasn't anyone considered it before?

My search brought me to George Spencer Brown's Book "Laws of Form" where he introduces a proto-arithmic and a proto-algebra of such a different kind, that I honestly didn't understand the book. But (rare) secondary literature helped and I found, that this book gave smarter people quite the interesting ideas (e.g. Niklas Luhmann). Perhaps you might give it a try. Anyway, in his calculus there IS a way to express time-dependant state.

Also I found Tony Hoare, who is a computer sience legend. He actually developed several calculi to express certain processes, specific to computer sience, that I never heard of before. He once (1995) was asked why his work was not adopted more widely. Here is his answer and it might also be the answer to your question:

> Ten years ago, researchers into formal methods (and I was the most mistaken among them) predicted that the programming world would embrace with gratitude every assistance promised by formalisation to solve the problems of reliability that arise when programs get large and more safety-critical. Programs have now got very large and very critical – well beyond the scale which can be comfortably tackled by formal methods. There have been many problems and failures, but these have nearly always been attributable to inadequate analysis of requirements or inadequate management control. It has turned out that the world just does not suffer significantly from the kind of problem that our research was originally intended to solve.

(From Wikipedia)

So in short: you could teach other kinds of logic to people. But they would be very complicated and most people wouldn't need these. So **classical logic is the best logic to teach** to a broad audience.

Hope this might help

Comment: This is interesting but actually quite different. I think there are too much statements (some do not have any meaning) in classical logic because the rules to create a statement in this logic are too permissive. It is very independent on wether a logic can or not handle the time . By the way I don't see any advantage to include the time natively in a logic since you can define theories with time inside a logic without time.

Comment: You can encode state or time in first order logic by adding a state or time parameter to each predicate. Also, there have been programming languages that were stateless, and you had to simulate state in just this way. You might be interested in this paper by John Backus: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/359576.359579

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers, one practical and one theoretical.

Practically speaking, since *no* known (and likely no possible) system of axioms (in any logic, classical or otherwise) that can express all true statements in arithmetic is complete, our choices are:

1. Use an incomplete system of axioms.
2. Stop using numbers.

Similarly, Alan Turing proved the halting problem for *all possible* languages that can be used for general computing. Our choices are:

1. Use languages that suffer from the halting problem.
2. Stop using computers.

So the answer to your question is because if we didn't, our entire civilization would immediately collapse and we would have no available mental tools left to rebuild it with.

The theoretical answer is that we use such systems and such languages because in such systems there exist many provable statements and many algorithms that can be proved to halt. Your interpretation of incompleteness is incorrect, it does not at all imply that no theorems in a "classical logic" system are provable. It is not only incorrect but self-contradictory. To state this in a complete logic system.

1. (Given) If Gödel has been proven correct, no theorem in a system of axioms powerful enough for arithmetic can be proven correct.
2. (Given) Gödel has been proven correct.
3. (Given) Gödel's theorem is a theorem in a system of axioms powerful enough for arithmetic.
4. (Conclusion) Gödel's theorem cannot be proven correct, which is a contradiction.

Comment: You seem to be trapped into classical logic. Intuitionistic logic is sound and complete. Actually you just can't build a sound system which is complete for the **classical logic** arithmetic semantics, i.e. the meaningless arithmetic introduced by someone mentally trapped into the meaningless classical logic.

Comment: No, I'm really not trapped in anything. I simply understand that the existence of a theorem which is true but cannot be proven does not in any way imply that no theorem can be both true and proven.

Comment: About computers, for sure there are programs which do not terminate, but if you use a constructive logic you can't define a problem which can't be solved by a program which terminates. The only programs which do not terminate do not solve any problem and there is no need for formalizing such programs or the result they would have. The negative result are only interesting when positive results are not obvious, if you get positive results by construction you are really not interested in negative results.

Comment: @François You don't understand the halting problem. And you're also sort of making my point: the existence of programs that cannot be proved to halt does not imply the non-existence of programs that can be proved to halt. If we stop using classical logic we stop using computers entirely.

Comment: For sure I understand the halting problem. But what it means is that random turing machine results are too permissive to serve as a foundation of mathematics. You can speak about things that are not well defined, but these things can't be part of our underlying logic. You can speak about these things as objects of theories and not as sentences of the logic.

Comment: @François as you clearly already know everything there is to know about logic, and cannot possibly be mistaken in your understanding of GIT or indeed anything else, I don't understand why you asked the question or why I should continue this discussion.

Comment: I don't know anything, I don't know if intuitionistic type theory is a constructive logic. But I assisted lectures and I had to prove myself than some TM do not halt. I even assisted a lecture about classifying not halting TM. But I maintain that the underlying theories of all these lectures is not suited as foundation for mathematics. We can think about it, we can't think within it.

Comment: @François you've got two options here. Either your premise is flawed, or everyone who cares deeply about and works in math is wrong. I suggest you either consider the former or prove the latter.

Comment: You are proposing two false dichotomies. We don't have to choose between an incomplete logic or no logic at all; we can choose a complete logic that is less powerful A lot of people in the field do make that very choice. And we don't have to choose between a Turing-complete language or no programming language at all; we can use a less powerful programming language (such as push-down automata) in which the halting problem is decidable.

Comment: @DavidGudeman tell you what: you write a web server and a web framework in such a language, and then we'll talk.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point. There is a big difference between using a language that is less powerful but can still do a lot of things, and not having a computer at all. You probably could implement a web server and framework in such a language because there is nothing in those applications that requires loops you can't prove will terminate.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Actually, you're missing the point. As I pointed out, there are two problems, one theoretical, one practical. Practically speaking, our choices are exactly to use TCLs or stop using computers. That's just a true statement about infrastructure.

Comment: No, that is not a true statement, as I have pointed out repeatedly. Our choice is to use TCLs or use some less powerful formalism but still continue to use computers. Almost all of the software in use could be written in a language that is not Turing complete.

Comment: @DavidGudeman No, it really is a true statement, because every general purpose computer uses an assembly language that is Turing complete. So step one is to rewrite all the assemblers. Actually, step one is to rewrite the history of computer science, including all the languages, starting in 1937. When you're done doing that, and somehow recreating every theory and concept ever developed using turing machines while using a more limited grammar, you can start rebuilding the entire software infrastructure of the planet. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Godel's first incompleteness theorem is as such:

Suppose F is an (omega) consistent, recursively axiomatizable formal system in which PA (really, we only need Q), holds. Then, there exists some undecidable sentence.

In particular, Godel constructs this undecidable sentence. He does not assume its nonexistence and then proceed to contradiction. In particular, he fixes a Godel numbering, uses that numbering to encode properties such as "provable", and then shows that this statement is undecidable. The Godel encoding merely amounts to defining a bijection between the language and the naturals, undecidability only uses negation introduction, hence is constructively acceptable. So where is the logical step that construcvists do not endorse? So, I believe your premise is wrong, but perhaps I am missing something.

However, don't believe me: from SEP's page:

"(though the incompleteness theorems do not essentially presuppose classical logic, but also apply to systems with, e.g., intuitionistic logic)."

But as to why people still use classic logic: it has an application in a wide variety of things, Constructive ZF + AOC implies LEM for example. Further it follows from some peoples philosophy of fact/truth- things are either true or not true. this premise is not unargued for, see Rumfit for example. Plus intuitionistic logic wrt to certain topics, say metaphysics, or the present, has extremely counterintuitive results, Dummett especially made this clear.

Answer (score 0):

> Often people don't realize that Godel Theorem do not apply in a constructive logic. Actually, the theorem could be written but it only proves something about classical logic.

Those statements [don't seem to be correct](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/).

> HA and PA are proof-theoretically equivalent, as will be shown in Section 4. Each is capable of (numeralwise) expressing its own proof predicate. By Gödel’s famous Incompleteness Theorem, if HA is consistent then neither HA nor PA can prove its own consistency.

(HA = Heyting arithmetic, PA = Peano arithmetic.)

I say "seem" because your description of "constructionist" logic is rather unclear/incomplete besides rejecting LEM. Doing just that would give you intuitionistic logic. You cannot however speak of a Gödel Incompleteness without defining a notion of arithmetic, which you don't seem to envisage how to do (in a way that would give you something other than HA, which basically just PA with the logic replaced with the intuitionistic one--see above ref.).

---

As for ITT, it's going to be like blind men discussing an elephant, since one version of it (extensional) has undecidable type checking, while the other looks quite unlike what mathematicians would accept (from Wikipedia):

> In contrast in intensional type theory type checking is decidable, but the representation of standard mathematical concepts is somewhat more cumbersome, since intensional reasoning requires using setoids or similar constructions. There are many common mathematical objects which are hard to work with or cannot be represented without this, for example, integer numbers, rational numbers, and real numbers. Integers and rational numbers can be represented without setoids, but this representation is difficult to work with. Cauchy real numbers cannot be represented without this.

Homotopy type theory, the groupoid/category-theoretic version of the latter, [also exhibits](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22130/homotopy-type-theory-and-g%C3%B6dels-incompleteness-theorems) a version of Gödel  incompleteness for its representation of arithmetic. Some proofs are given in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.10482 ; see also [How do we construct the Gödel’s sentence in Martin-Löf type theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272982/how-do-we-construct-the-g%C3%B6del-s-sentence-in-martin-l%C3%B6f-type-theory).

(As explained in [this talk](https://youtu.be/_VaxLrExaPM?t=725) the nuisance with intensional ITT starts with the fact that in it you cannot prove that two functions equal everywhere are actually equal, i.e. it suffers from "Leibniz incompleteness". Which is why you need setoids and the like.)

And from a [Joyal talk on HoTT](https://youtu.be/HRBShaxIblI?t=532), you basically have to assume the equivalent of the induction principle disguised as the "Voevodsky's univalence". One can explain induction to highschool children, whereas for the "generalized Blakers-Massey theorem" or "Goodwillie calculus"... Yes, HoTT looks amazing as FoM to *some* mathematicians, but you yourself admit not understanding it much (or even mention it as such)...